# Rails 3: What is the best way to implement a Facebook style "Friend List" feature in Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an application that currently fetches data from mySQL DB. And I have a `Person` table which contains columns: `Name`, `Gender`, `Email`, `Hobby` and etc.

I want to implement a "grouping-like" feature so that users can be categorized into a group by specific columns (e.g. `Gender`)

What I have is something like this:
[image]

What I want to implement is to create two groups Boys/Girls by their gender and with a little `+` sign so that we can expand it and see what people is in the group:
[image]

What would be the best way to do this?
UPDATE:
My way to implements this:

```
my_controller.rb:

def index
  @people = Person.find_by_sql(*some sql stuff*)
  @persons = @people.group_by { |t| t.gender }
end
```

then in view file

```
view.html.erb
<% @persons.sort.each do |gender, person_list| %>
  <h2><%= gender %></h2>
  <% for person in person_list %>
    *some code here*
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can uses scopes. In your Person model file, add the following:

```
scope :boys, where(:gender => "Male")
scope :girls, where(:gender => "Female")
```

Then in your controller, you can create variables for each gender group.

```
@boys = Person.boys
@girls = Person.girls
```

Finally iterate over @boys and @girls in your view.

Comment: Since `Model` are the right way to deal with the database stuff, you approach seems to be more appropriate in this case. I will recommend this solution to anyone who view this quesiton.